# creating a heatplot with ggplot column wise

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have the following (small) melted data. Its a R RDS file, best way to transfer R datasets! You need `data.table` library.

```
> urlf = 'http://emboss.math.yorku.ca/results/ove_m_rds'
> ove.m = readRDS(gzcon(url(urlf))) ##download the data.table
```

Basically, I have the following code to make a heat plot of the data:

```
  gg = ggplot(ove.m, aes(variable, state)) 
  gg = gg +  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white")
  gg = gg +  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#1f78b4")
```

But the problem with this is the colors are adjusted to ALL the values in the matrix. I want the colors to represent the **column** only. So the resulting heat map looks like the following for the above data:

[image]

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want the color in Genome %, State 9 to represent the value for the row with Genome % and State 9?

Comment: Yes. The colors are specific to columns only. The way I have it right now, state 1 and genome% is at ~70% which dominates everything else but the other columns have nothing to do with it. Actually I am currently working on a mathematical formula that will modify the numbers for me to see if I can scale everything accordingly

Comment: Oh, I see. So you're just saying the darkness of the cell column should be based on the column not the entire matrix. Got it. Yes, re-scaling the `value` data would be a straight line path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlf = 'http://emboss.math.yorku.ca/results/ove_m_rds'
ove.m = readRDS(gzcon(url(urlf))) ##download the data.table

a           <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 9, ncol = 7))
names(a)    <- unique(levels(ove.m$variable))
ove.m$state <- as.numeric(ove.m$state)
for(i in 1:9){
  a$genomecoverage[i] <- as.numeric(ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "genomecoverage" & ove.m$state == i ])
  a$cpgisland[i]      <- ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "cpgisland" & ove.m$state == i ]
  a$exon[i]           <- ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "exon" & ove.m$state == i ]
  a$gene[i]           <- ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "gene" & ove.m$state == i ]
  a$tes[i]            <- ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "tes" & ove.m$state == i ]
  a$tss[i]            <- ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "tss" & ove.m$state == i ]
  a$tss2kb[i]         <- ove.m$value[ove.m$variable == "tss2kb" & ove.m$state == i ]
}

b       <- as.data.frame(apply(a, 2, scale))
b$state <- 1:9
c       <- melt(b, id.vars = "state")

gg = ggplot(ove.m, aes(variable, state)) 
gg = gg +  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white")
gg = gg +  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "#1f78b4")
gg
```

Comment: Ahh, interesting, didn't know there was a `scale` function. Furthermore, to those reading: this solution essentially rescales the values. AFAIK ggplot has no internal way to 'group' the values and create a heat map based on the grouped values.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer to this question. I was looking for a solution in which ggplot2 could identify the column groups and create a color scale on the groupings.

The alternative solution was to scale the values accordingly. For each entry of the column `x`, the formula is

`x - min(column) divided by max(column)`